# React setState working slowly when using in onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a textarea which i'm trying to get value and set to state. 
but it's working so slowly so i'm typing some thing and i see value after 10-15 second. Why can happened?

my state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      comment: ''
    };
    this.getValue = this.getValue.bind(this)
  }
```

my onChange function:

```
getValue = (e) => {
   this.setState({comment: e.target.value})
}
```

my textarea:

```
 <textarea
   type="text"
   value={this.state.comment}
   onChange={this.getValue}
 />
```

Comment: why do you write "this.getValue = this.getValue.bind(this)" in your constructor if you are using arrow function for your onChange function? and please show your component fully snippet

Comment: The code seems to be fine , Show is your whole code for further clarification

Answer (score 1):

The below snippet seems to work fine and without the delay that you speak of, is your code similar to this? Can you share some more details? Are state updates working correctly in the rest of the application?

```js
class Thingy extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      comment: ''
    };
  }
  
  getValue = (e) => {
   this.setState({comment: e.target.value})
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <p>{this.state.comment}</p>
      <textarea
       type="text"
       value={this.state.comment}
       onChange={this.getValue}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Thingy />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using hooks?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [comment, setComment] = useState('');

  return (
    <div>
      <textarea
        type="text"
        value={comment}
        onChange={e => setComment(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: I need to put const ... after render or top of the component ?

Comment: hooks is used in a function component not in class !  u need to import  useState from react and then declare  your state and your method at the top of the function! form more detail check here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: @adel okey i need to put my text area in the function ? can u give me some example with my example. I didn't understand clearly :(

Comment: @user3348410 I will update my answer with a complete React compenent. Give me a minute.

Comment: @adel Thank you for providing information that I haven't provided. I naively assumed hooks would already be widely established. Dumb me.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me. See it in a fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/wbkjenay/

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { comment: '' }
  }

  getValue = e => { this.setState({comment: e.target.value}) }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <textarea
            type="text"
            value={this.state.comment}
            onChange={this.getValue}
        />
        <div>this.state.comment: {this.state.comment}</div>     
    </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

well this is hooks method hope it help!

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "name"
  const [name, setname] = useState();

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Your name :{name}</p>
      <textarea onChange={e => setname(e.target.value)} value={name}/>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Example
```

Comment: Ou thanks but if i change my class component to function base component my constructor state and another things not working